# VB.NET LINQ Group By Multiple Fields - Still produces duplicates

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

I'm trying to use a Group By to produce a set of unique results based on two keys, with a third field being a collection of objects (the result of a group join), but my current approach appears to be producing one row for each match from the group join i.e. a regular inner join.

Here's the scenario:

```
Table A
--
PersonID
1
2
3

Table B
--
PersonID    AttributeType    AttributeValue    SomeDate
1           Type1            blah              2017-11-29
1           Type2            blah              2017-11-29
1           Type3            blah              2017-11-28
2           Type1            blah              2017-11-29
2           Type2            blah              2017-11-26
2           Type3            blah              2017-11-29
3           Type1            blah              2017-11-29
3           Type2            blah              2017-11-25
3           Type3            blah              2017-11-25
```

Ideal Output

```
Results
--
PersonID    Date        Type1    Type2    Type3
1           2017-11-29  blah     blah     NULL
1           2017-11-28  NULL     NULL     blah
2           2017-11-29  blah     NULL     blah
2           2017-11-26  NULL     blah     NULL
3           2017-11-29  blah     NULL     NULL
3           2017-11-25  NULL     blah     blah
```

Here's my attempt:

```
From A in TableA
Group Join B in TableB On A.PersonID Equals B.PersonID Into personsAttributes = Group
From att in personsAttributes
Group PersonID = att.PersonID, Date = att.SomeDate, Attributes = personsAttributes.Where(Function(a) att.SomeDate = a.SomeDate) By att.PersonID, att.SomeDate Into results = Group
From result in results
Let Type1 = result.Attributes.Where(Function(a) a.AttributeType = "Type1").Select(Function(a) a.AttributeValue).FirstOrDefault()
etc...
Select New MyType With
{
    .PersonID = result.PersonID,
    .Date = result.Date,
    .Type1 = Type1,
    etc...
}
```

The desired output is one row for each unique combination of PersonID and Date.

I've been reading about the issues around anonymous types and key values in VB.NET, and I'm wondering if it's related? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types

(NOTE: The join between A and B is required in the first place because there are additional Where clauses I've omitted)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured this out myself. Instead of using a From clause followed by Group By after the group join, I use the method syntax and call GroupBy on the results of the group join directly. When I specify the key, I use an anonymous object and specify that both properties are "Key" properties. (Is there some limitation around compound keys in LINQ query syntax?)

Then I pull the ID and Date from the Key property, and I can work with the grouped results in a similar way as in the question.

```
Let results = personsAttributes.GroupBy(Function(p) New With {Key .ID = p.PersonID, Key .Date = p.SomeDate})
From result in results
Select New MyType With
{
    .PersonID = result.Key.ID,
    .Date = result.Key.Date,
    .Type1 = result.Where(Function(r) r.AttributeType = "Type1").Select(Function(r) r.AttributeValue).FirstOrDefault()
}
```